# How to purge data older than 30 days from Redis Server

Tags: redis, logstash, kibana

I am using Logstash, Redis DB, ElasticSearch and Kibana 3 for my centalize log server. It's working fine and I am able to see the logs in Kibana. Now I want to keep only 30 days log in ElasticSearch and Redis Server. Is it possible to purge data from Redis?

I am using the below configuration

indexer.conf

```
input {
redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 6379
    type => "redis-input"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"
    format => "json_event"
}
}
output {
 stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
 elasticsearch {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
 }
}
```

shipper.conf

```
input {
  file {
  type => "nginx_access"
  path => ["/var/log/nginx/**"]
  exclude => ["*.gz", "error.*"]
  discover_interval => 10
 }
}

filter {
  grok {
  type => nginx_access
  pattern => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
 }
}

output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
  redis { host => "127.0.0.1" data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}
```

As per this configuration the shipper file is sending data to Redis DB with the key "logstash". From the redis db documents I came to know that we can set TTL for any key with expire command to purge them. But when I am searching for the key "logstash" in redis db `keys logstash` or `keys *`I am not getting any result. Please let me know if my question is not understandable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key:value store. Keys are unique by definition. So if you want to store several logs, you need to add a new entry, with a new key and associated value, for each log.

So it seems to me you have a fundamental flaw here, as you're always using the same key for all your logs. Try with a different key for each log (not sure how to do that).

Then set TTL to 30 days.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late response. Why I am not able to search the keys that is "logstash" in redis-cli? Even if `keys *` is also not providing me the answer "logstash".